# How can I define a one to many constraint between columns of the same table?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, unique-constraint

I'm creating an IDs table in PostgreSQL to represent the relationship between multiple foreign IDs - call them `a`, `b` and `c`.

I happen to know that the foreign IDs have one-to-many relationships between them:

`a 1..* b`
`b 1..* c`

I'd like to represent them as a single table (see below), but enforce the one-to-many invariant between `a` & `b`, & between `b` and `c`.

Is that possible?

Examples:
The following insertions would be illegal:

| pk | a | b | c | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p15 | a1 | b11 | c111 | c111 already exists |
| p16 | a1 | b21 | c213 | b21 already exists for a2 |
| p17 | a2 | b11 | c214 | b11 already exists for a1 |

Given the following legal table:

| pk | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | a1 | b11 | c111 |
| p2 | a1 | b11 | c112 |
| p3 | a1 | b12 | c121 |
| p4 | a1 | b12 | c122 |
| p5 | a2 | b21 | c211 |
| p6 | a2 | b21 | c212 |
| p7 | a2 | b22 | c221 |
| p8 | a2 | b22 | c222 |
| p9 | null | b31 | c311 |
| p10 | a3 | null | c312 |
| p11 | a3 | b31 | null |
| p12 | null | null | c314 |
| p13 | null | b31 | null |
| p14 | a3 | null | null |

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but you're probably going about it the wrong way, given the presence of as many NULLs and a "primary key" that isn't doing anything other than saying "I'm row 15!".  Can you provide some context around exactly what data you're working with and what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: I'm associating our own ID for an entity (the pk in this table) with multiple foreign IDs that we are correlating together. We receive the foreign IDs in a haphazard manner - a message may contain one or more of them depending on which system it comes from, and so we have to do complicated logic to correlate them.

Comment: Gotcha.  Trigger/procedure logic is likely your only option.

Comment: This might be simpler, yet. Please disclose your version of Postgres and more about the use case. `INSERT` only? Can there be `DELETE` or `UPDATE`? Roughly how many distinct `a`, `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be done by `TRIGGER`, because it is too complex for `CHEKC`constraint

For updating you need a similar trigger/function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tabl1
>     ("pk" varchar(5), "a" varchar(6), "b" varchar(6), "c" varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tabl1
>     ("pk", "a", "b", "c")
> VALUES
>     ('p1', 'a1', 'b11', 'c111'),
>     ('p2', 'a1', 'b11', 'c112'),
>     ('p3', 'a1', 'b12', 'c121'),
>     ('p4', 'a1', 'b12', 'c122'),
>     ('p5', 'a2', 'b21', 'c211'),
>     ('p6', 'a2', 'b21', 'c212'),
>     ('p7', 'a2', 'b22', 'c221'),
>     ('p8', 'a2', 'b22', 'c222'),
>     ('p9', NULL, 'b31', 'c311'),
>     ('p10', 'a3', NULL, 'c312'),
>     ('p11', 'a3', 'b31', NULL),
>     ('p12', NULL, NULL, 'c314'),
>     ('p13', NULL, 'b31', NULL),
>     ('p14', 'a3', NULL, NULL)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_insert()
> RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
>    BEGIN
>    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabl1 WHERE "c" = NEW."c" AND "b" = NEW."b" ) then
>        raise EXCEPTION 'The column %  already  with %',NEW."c",NEW."b";
>    ELSIF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabl1 WHERE "a" <> NEW."a" AND "b" = NEW."b" ) then
>            raise EXCEPTION 'The column %  already  has already a column',NEW."b";
>    END IF;
>    RETURN NEW;
>    END;
> $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE
>  INSERT
> ON tabl1
> FOR EACH ROW
> EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_insert();
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tabl1
>     ("pk", "a", "b", "c")
> VALUES
>     ('p15', 'a1', 'b11', 'c111')
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  The column c111  already  with b11
> ```

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_insert() line 4 at RAISE

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO tabl1
>     ("pk", "a", "b", "c")
> VALUES
> ('p16' , 'a1'   , 'b21'  , 'c213' )
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  The column b21  already  has already a column
> ```

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_insert() line 6 at RAISE

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO tabl1
>     ("pk", "a", "b", "c")
> VALUES
> ('p17',   'a2',   'b11'   ,'c214')
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  The column b11  already  has already a column
> ```

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_insert() line 6 at RAISE

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tabl1
> ```
>
> ```
> pk  | a    | b    | c   
> :-- | :--- | :--- | :---
> p1  | a1   | b11  | c111
> p2  | a1   | b11  | c112
> p3  | a1   | b12  | c121
> p4  | a1   | b12  | c122
> p5  | a2   | b21  | c211
> p6  | a2   | b21  | c212
> p7  | a2   | b22  | c221
> p8  | a2   | b22  | c222
> p9  | null | b31  | c311
> p10 | a3   | null | c312
> p11 | a3   | b31  | null
> p12 | null | null | c314
> p13 | null | b31  | null
> p14 | a3   | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=475cfd37172f424c9a02cf39ca2e411d)*